# Complex numbers to normal form

Tags: complex-numbers

Express $i^{2012} $ in the form $a+ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.  Please send with all methods.? I try to many ways.  I didn't understand how do do it?

Comment: Can u express it?

Comment: Write $i$ in the $a + bi$ format, then $i^2$, then $i^3$, then $i^4$, then $i^5$, then ... keep doing this until you spot a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in general, when $\exists\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}\space\wedge\space\exists\space\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\text{z}^\text{n}=\left(\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}\right)^\text{n}=\left|\text{z}\right|^\text{n}\cdot e^{\text{n}\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}=$$
$$\left|\text{z}\right|^\text{n}\cdot\cos\left(\text{n}\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)\right)+\left|\text{z}\right|^\text{n}\cdot\sin\left(\text{n}\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)\right)i\tag1$$

Where $0\le\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\le2\pi$ and $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

So, for your problem:

- $$\left|i\right|=1\tag2$$
- $$\arg\left(i\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\tag3$$

So:

$$i^{2012}=1^{2012}\cdot\cos\left(2012\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi\text{k}\right)\right)+1^{2012}\cdot\sin\left(2012\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi\text{k}\right)\right)i=$$
$$1^{2012}\cdot1+1^{2012}\cdot0=1\tag4$$

Comment: Dear I want a+ib form

Comment: @AsamHussain Well, you have that. Look before my $\left(1\right)$

Comment: Please explain different method

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Is answer 1? Thank you very much

Comment: bahahaha. I think this one wins for most unnecessarily complicated. Upvoted.

Comment: @JanEerland. When you look through his other posts, he is posting questions for a school assignment (as he admits) and wants us to do the work...

Answer (score 1):

$$i^2=-1 ,\quad \space i^3=-i \quad  ,i^4=1\space $$
Genralising 
$$i^{4n}=1 ,\quad \space i^{4n+1}=i \quad  ,i^{4n+2}=-1\quad i^{4n+3}=-i\space $$

Answer (score 1):

$2012/4 = 503$. So $i^{2012} = i^{4\times 503} = (i^4)^{503} = (i^2i^2)^{503} = (-1\times -1)^{503} = 1^{503} = 1.$ That is, $a = 1, b= 0$. Easy peasy.